# image not showing in php using img src tag

Tags: php

I want to display a image simply. But this php script is not executing properly. what's the problem happening with  I can't understand

```
<?php
$path="india.png";
echo "<img src='localhost/suman_php/india.png'>"; //not working
$path="C:/Users/SUMAN/Desktop/thor.jpg";
echo "<img src='"$path"'>"; //also not working
?>
```

when I try to run this code [this kind of unexpected output is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH6PZ.png)

Comment: try like this `http://localhost/your rest url`

Comment: if you have created and folder and that image into same folder then no need to add path there just add image name and check

Comment: It should be either `echo "<img src='$path'>";` or `echo "<img src='" . $path . "'>";`. The `src` should to be an URL, not an absolute file path. Also, in your first example: `src="localhost/..."` will look for a folder called `localhost/....`. When writing URL's, you _always_ need to include the schema: `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: but instead of localhost if I want to use any other location to browse and upload image, then What changes need to be done? that is if I want to upload image from my desktop (second path location in my code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this one with added schema http:// with an image url. Image path should be correct.

```
<?php
   echo "<img src='http://localhost/suman_php/india.png'>"; 
?>
```

Comment: but instead of localhost if I want to use any other location to browse and upload image, then What changes need to be done? that is if I want to upload image from my desktop (second path location in my code) –

Comment: @Anirban You need to upload image in your folder like you need to add or upload the image to folder "suman_php" and access it. Means your image must be in server folders. Server folder means all folder which in side the "htdocs" folder.

Comment: but in the case of registration form fillup we have to upload image from any other locations, in that case how it is solved? as a user how can I store images into server

Comment: You can add file input field in your registration form so where user can upload the image which will be uploaded in your server. If you don't know how the image upload in PHP then you can check the below link .  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp ,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Answer (score -1):

please try this code...

```
<?php
echo '<img src="http://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg" title="Title of image" alt="alt text here"/>';
?>
```